# How to create Dashboard Menu Like Realplayer App

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I create a dashboard menu like

Realplayer App..

[image]

or like this one

[image]

Any help would be great so i can start in the right direction..
So far i have tried few things but i am not able to achieve this kind of layout.

Comment: For the first screen, this could be helpful: http://www.androidviews.net/2012/10/radial-menu-widget/. For the second, I suspect it could be just a bunch of nested layouts.

Comment: For the second one you only need a GridView.

Comment: @IceMAN Thanks for the link man . I will definitely try it , for the second screen how should i start , like place png images as background for button in a selector file and then place them in a nested layout

Comment: @Teovald the problem i faced with gridview is the spacing between the columns..

Comment: @Ravi android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
and/or  
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"  
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"  
should help you

Comment: @Teovald after trying gridview with settings you said column space still exist

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, I quess you will just need a bunch of images and then just place them in the way you want. As for the second one, a GridLayout might help you out. Or just use a couple  of LinearLayouts.

Comment: the problem i always face is when i place png image on button and place the buttons in linear there always appears space bw them.